# Present a rotatable view controller over another view controller locked to portrait orientation on iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, rotation

I have a fullscreen view controller, let's call it the background view controller, that is my root view controller. I want to present a view controller on top of it, in the foreground, that doesn't fill the screen. I've done this somewhat successfully using `self.presentViewController()` with the foreground view controller's `modalPresentationStyle` set to `OverCurrentContext`.

My problem is that I want my background view controller to stay locked to portrait, and I want my foreground view controller to be able to rotate with the device. So far I've been able to rotate the foreground view controller, but the background view controller rotates with it. Both view controllers control UIScrollViews, if that make a difference.

I've tried overriding `supportedInterfaceOrientations()` and setting it to `Portrait` and `All` for the background and foreground view controller respectively, but that results in nothing rotating at all. I've also tried playing with `shouldAutorotate()` but that didn't help.

How can I accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: no answer in ~4y! I have exactly this problem and this question is the best "answer" I could find... meaning nothing. Got an answer elsewhere ?